# gnuplot : plot pipe output

Tags: pipe, gnuplot

I have the output a pipe secuence

```
command_a | command_b | ... | command_n
```

the output is a sequence a number

```
4.2
-1
...
0.2
```

I can use gnuplot to plot this numbers ? (added gnuplot to pipe sequence )

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with the following?

`plot "< command_a | command_b | ... | command_n"`

concrete example:

`plot "< awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' datafile |sort -nk1"`

it works for me (tested with gnuplot 4.2 and 5.0 on a linux system).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the '-' source in the plot command. You just need to pipe the command file first and then the data file. For example:

test.gnuplot:

```
plot '-' with lines
```

Example command line:

```
[command generating data] | cat test.gnuplot - | gnuplot -persist
```

Comment: I get this Failed to initialize wxWidgets.
         line 69: warning: Too many axis ticks requested (>6)
         line 69: warning: Too many axis ticks requested (>6)
         line 69: warning: Too many axis ticks requested (>7)